Next Auth: Custom Session Google Provider
I have a code in the below in NextAuth 5.
And I have 2 method for authentication.
In my confugiration, I will send the user data and save on the database. Also, I have the custom session to add user infomasion on database like database id, etc..
Problem:
the custom session only work on credential method
And on google method, i cant do custom session on my configuration. And always have a default google response like:
{
  user: {
    name: 'google name',
    email: 'email@gmail.com',
    image: ''link photo",
    id: 'id'
  },
  expires: '2024-10-21T15:44:17.321Z'
}

question:
How to make custom session for Google Provider
Code:
callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account }) {
      if (account?.provider === "google") {
        let dbUser = await prisma.users.findUnique({
          where: { email: user.email as string },
        });

        if (!dbUser) {
          await prisma.users.create({
            data: {
              email: user.email as string,
              nama: user.name as string,
              provider: "google",
              provider_id: account.providerAccountId as string,
              image: user.image as string,
              status: true,
            },
          });
        }
      }

      return true;
    },

    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token.id = user.id as string;
        token.email = user.email as string;
        token.nama = user.nama;
        token.alamat = user.alamat;
        token.status = user.status;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token) {
        session.user.id = token.id;
        session.user.email = token.email;
        session.user.nama = token.nama;
        session.user.alamat = token.alamat;
        session.user.status = token.status;
        session.user.createdAt = token.createdAt;
        session.user.updatedAt = token.updatedAt;
        session.user.tes = token.tes
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
});

Custom Session on Google Provider
